# new-session in tmux config starts two sessions

Tags: tmux

File `~/.tmux.conf`

```
new-session -n terminal
```

Run tmux by command:

```
tmux
```

Result: two sessions found in sessions lists (check by `ctrl+b s`)

```
(0) + 1: 1 windows (attached)
(1) + terminal: 1 windows
```

I would like to have only `terminal` session which I've defined in my config file.

Answer (score 2):

`(0) + 1: 1 windows (attached)` - first session that created by the `tmux` command.

Then tmux load configs and create one more session `(1) + terminal: 1 windows` because you have `new-session -n terminal` line in **.tmux.conf**

To create one session remove `new-session -n terminal` from **.tmux.conf** and start tmux as `tmux` or `tmux new -s session_name`

Comment: That what I thought so. However I would like to keep config because I start several preconfigured sessions at once.
Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

So I've created a script which omits creation additional session (only those defined in configuration)

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```